# AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute '_node'

Tags: python

I am doing Udacity's implementing a Route Planner project, the error is showing below, I have already down-grade networkx==2.3, but still have this error, is anybody can help?

```py
D:\Self Learning\Anaconda3\envs\tf2.0.0rc1\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\reportviews.py in __init__(self, graph)
    166 
    167     def __init__(self, graph):
--> 168         self._nodes = graph._node
    169 
    170     # Mapping methods

AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute '_node'
```

```py
# this is the reportviews.py __init__(self,graph)
    __slots__ = '_nodes',

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {'_nodes': self._nodes}

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self._nodes = state['_nodes']

    def __init__(self, graph):
        self._nodes = graph._node     #line 168, but I don't know what wrong with it?

    # Mapping methods
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._nodes)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._nodes)

    def __getitem__(self, n):
        return self._nodes[n]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `self._nodes = graph.nodes`?

Comment: I tried it, still have error

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: D:\Self Learning\Anaconda3\envs\tf2.0.0rc1\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\graph.py in nodes(self)
    752 
    753         """
--> 754         nodes = NodeView(self)
    755         # Lazy View creation: overload the (class) property on the instance
    756         # Then future G.nodes use the existing View

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: something like this, exceeded max recursion depth. It will occur when I don't write _.

Comment: Well this is clearly a step further from the error you post in your question - you are at least accessing an existing attribute on `Graph`.

Comment: Hi, do you know how can I solve it?